# WPF data context for design time and run time

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I'm learning WPF, MVVM Light and the ViewModelLocator pattern and running into difficulties with my main window's data context.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
   {
      public ViewModelLocator()
      {
         var mainModel = new MainModel();
         Main = new MainViewModel(mainModel);
      }

      public MainViewModel Main { get; private set; }

      public static ViewModelLocator Instance
      {
         get { return Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator; }
      }
   }
```

and in my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

When I set the data context in my main window using:

```
DataContext="Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}"
```

it compiles but all of MainViewModel's properies I bind to elsewhere in the xaml show up red with tooltip "cannot resolve symbol". I thought I could get around this by also specifying a designer-only data context:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDemo.Windows.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WPFDemo.Converters"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDemo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:WPFDemo.Models"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WPFDemo.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance, Type=viewModels:MainViewModel,
    IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```

but the compiler doesn't like that last line ("The character ',' is unexpected at this position", referrring to the first comma). Note I'm not using ExpressionBlend, but I thought I heard in a course that this line would enable VisualStudio designer as well:

```
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

How do I use a ViewModelLocator while still enabling Visual Studio to recognize bound properties at design time?

Comment: And what happened when you removed that comma which shouldn't be there?  (and, yes, you can use design time data in VS)

Comment: You need to wrap this in brackets `{ }` --- `DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`

Comment: @Will - then the entire line gets flagged as an error, "no parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Comment: @bdimag - Yep, that did it! Please post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @bdimag is also correct, your binding is not contained within curly brackets. (removing all this... I've never seen that before, would assume it is incorrect syntax, but I can't test that out right now :/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default data context should also work in design time:

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

If not, try to compile the proyect and check out again.
You can manage the properties values that you want to show in design time by using the `IsInDesignMode` property that the `MvvmLight Toolkit` provides. By default the `MainViewModel`'s constructor looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        }
        else
        {
            // Code runs "for real"
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 14):

The last line will work nicely if you remove the comma after `d:DesignInstance`:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel,
IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```