# Binding to Parent of nested UserControl during design-time and runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am working with a custom window class that adds some behaviours to the window:

```cs
class CustomWindow : Window {
    public CustomWindow() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My current `MainWindow.xaml` looks as expected:

```xml
<local:CustomWindow ...>
    <!-- ... -->
</local:CustomWindow>
```

Now I wanted to host the content of the window in a custom container which should be the root element of the window itself but I struggled to implement the automatic creation of the container in the first place. Thus I am doing manually what I wanted to automate now with a "hardcoded" control:

```xml
<local:CustomWindow ...>
    <local:CustomUserControl>
        <!-- ... -->
    </local:CustomUserControl>
</local:CustomWindow>
```

In order to display the content that has been added via XAML I have introduced a Content property like this:

```cs
[ContentProperty("InnerContent")]
public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InnerContent", typeof(object), 
                                    typeof(CustomUserControl));

    public object InnerContent
    {
        get => GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And a `ContentPresenter` in the XAML file with `Content="{Binding Path=InnerContent, ElementName=customUserControl}"`. At this point I am struggling with some further bindings I want to achieve. I have a TextBlock I want to bind to a property of the parent window now. The hierarchy looks as follows:

```
CustomWindow
|- CustomUserControl
   |- ...
      |- TextBlock
```

When I set the `Text` property to `{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomWindow}}}` this works during runtime of course but not during design-time in the window designer. And of course I cannot use this binding with a design `DataContext` that I have introduced like this `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:FakeCustomUserControlData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`.

At this point I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to have design-time data in the `CustomUserControl.xaml` designer, while in the `MainWindow.xaml` designer and during runtime I get the real data about the parent? (I noticed during testing that the `Parent` property of the `CustomUserControl` is null during its constructor so I wasn't able to obtain the data of a parent window if there exists one.)
2. Is there actually a way to "inject" the `CustomUserControl` into the window without manually having to add it to the window? I tried to replace the `Content` property in the `CustomWindow` constructor but it got replaced during some point and was never visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there actually a way to "inject" the `CustomUserControl` into the window without manually having to add it to the window?

Define a custom template for the window that includes your `UserControl`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        ...>
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <local:CustomUserControl Background="White">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </local:CustomUserControl>
            </AdornerDecorator>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>the content...</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> Is it possible to have design-time data in the CustomUserControl.xaml designer, while in the `MainWindow.xaml` designer and during runtime I get the real data about the parent?

You should be able to set a design time data context for the `UserControl`: [WPF data context for design time and run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189815/wpf-data-context-for-design-time-and-run-time).

Comment: I took your idea with the `ControlTemplate` even further since I stumbled upon [this article](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/). Instead of the custom chrome that the writer is using inside the template I just placed my `CustomUserControl` and was able to set the `DataContext` of it in the `OnApplyTemplate` override - this was exactly what I was looking for when talking about the "injection". Thank you very much for your suggestion!